# What are scheduled callbacks?

Tags: wp-cron, cron, core

I was taking a look at the inner workings of the Cron System, and found something odd: apparently, you can set a callback to event recurrence schedules. However, I can't find any documentation on that topic. The only indication I've found of what this is used for comes from `_wp_cron`'s dockbloc: *Runs scheduled callbacks or spawns cron for all scheduled events.* Is that used anywhere by WordPress core? Is that a left over from the early days of WordPress? Is that meant for public usage?

For reference, take a look at [line 1022 in wp-includes/cron.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.4/src/wp-includes/cron.php#L1022):

```
if ( isset( $schedules[ $hook ]['callback'] )
        && ! call_user_func( $schedules[ $hook ]['callback'] )
) {
        continue;
}
```

Here `$schedules` is the return value of `wp_get_schedules`.